# PHP - Update Text on the Screen with AJAX and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I have an issue where i am trying to use PHP/AJAX/JQuery to update text on the screen.

If you view my site i am working on here: [My Site](http://discovertheplanet.net/general_notes.php)

You will see a list of notes on the left.

Now im kind of new and threw myself in the deep end with this but ive learnt so much and want to see it through.

Basiclaly that page you view there are two divs one on the left and one on the right. The left clearly containing the note names, however on the right when you click that note it should display text in the currently empty right DIV.

In the console i have got it retrieving the ID's if you view the console whilst clicking on one of the options you will see it reaches that point.

**An Example:**
Say i click on the first one it checks the database for the text associated with ID 1 and displays it on the page

**My general_notes.PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<title>Juan - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/igotswag.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/swaganimations.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>


<!-- Header Area -->
<table class="header-container">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40%; text-align: left;"><a href="index.php"><img class="hover-cursor" src="Images/TEAMS_Logo.png"></a></td>
        <td style="width: 10%;" class="custom-header">TEAMS Wiki <span style="font-size: 30px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></td>
        <td style="width: 40%;">
            <table style="text-align: right; width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 24px; text-align: right;" class="hvr-icon-grow"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="pull-down-container">
    <div class="panel1">
        <br />
        <p>Now you see me!</p>
    </div>
    <p class="slide" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="pull-me hvr-icon-hang" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">More</div>
    </p>
</div>
<!-- End Header Area -->



<!-- Main Body Area -->

<?php include 'noteContent.php'; ?>

<!-- End Main Body Area -->

<!-- Footer Area -->

<!-- End Footer Area -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the main body area you will see noteContent include.

**noteContent.php:**

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php

//Defining my queries
$getNotes = "SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
$getTemplateNotes = "SELECT TemplateNoteID, TemplateNoteName, TemplateNote FROM TemplateNotes";
$getReplaceVariables = "SELECT ReplaceVariableID, ReplaceVariableName, ReplaceVariableNote FROM ReplaceVariables";

$resultNotes = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $getNotes );
$resultTemplate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getTemplateNotes);
$resultVariables = sqlsrv_query($conn, $getReplaceVariables);


if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) {
    $showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = " . $_POST['noteid'];
    $showNotes    = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);
}


// Still in development
// ====================
//  This is very rough and ready just for testing
//  On Initial Page load, we don't have anything so this is okish



if( $resultNotes === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
if( $resultTemplate === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

if( $resultVariables === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

?>



<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";

        while( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output noSelect' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">

    </div>
</div>
```

**The JQuery part:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel1').slideToggle('slow')
    });
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel2').slideToggle('slow')
    });
    $('.pull-me').click(function()
    {
        $('.panel3').slideToggle('slow')
    });

    $("#selection-box1").change(function()
    {
        document.location.href = $(this).val();
    });

    $(".output").click(function () {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        console.log('Got here - Noteid = ' + noteid);
        $("#right-box").load("noteContent.php", {noteid: noteid});
    });
});
```

So in "*noteContent.php*" what am i putting in the right box to echo the text associated to the ID of the note name clicked on?

Comment: And what is the problem? What do you see in a developers console? Why do you `load()` `connectionDetails.php`?

Comment: EDIT: oh i see the Load, like i said, im kind of new and from tutorials thats what i thought i had to call from to say where my database details are. Also in the developers console i see the bit where it says it reached that note and got the ID, but im asking what i out in the right div box to echo the text associated with the ID from the database

Comment: it looks like your `connectionDetails.php` doesn't return any results.

Comment: I changed this too load() the noteContent.php and now when you click an option it just displays the note names bar, again. I feel like im closer but further.

Comment: If `isset($_POST['noteid'])` - output one data, else - other data